# Basis of the topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by cylinders

Tags: general-topology

Let $j=1,...,n$ be a fixed index.

Given $h,R>0$ and $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ create the cylinder $C_{2h,R}(p)=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n||x_j-p_j|<h,\sum_{i\neq j}(x_i-p_i)^2<R^2\}$.

> Is it true that these cylinders form a basis of the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

My try: I want to show that $C_{2h,R}(p)$ contains an open ball, and it is easy to check that $B_{\min(h,R)}(p)$ does the job.

Now I should show that any open ball contains a cylinder, and here I'm stuck.

Comment: What is your strategy to prove that the cylinders are a basis? i.e. what are the properties you want to check?

Comment: Showing that any ball contains a cylinder, and any cilinder contains a ball. Right, I'm not proving this.

Comment: I think calculating the supremum of the distance from the center of the cylinder to the other points of it is sufficient to prove that.

Comment: Just to put this into context, you are basically proving $\mathbb{R}^n$ is naturally homemorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1} \times \mathbb{R}$